# How to decouple repository and entities

Tags: model-view-controller, model, ddd-repositories

This is a question on domain model design.

Let's say for a domain design involving users and groups, we have the following interfaces to implement:

```cs
interface IUser
{
    string Name{get;}
    DateTime DOB {get;}
}

interface IGroup
{
    string Name {get;}
    bool IsUserInGroup(IUser user); // #1
    void IncludeUser(IUser user);   // #2
    void ExcludeUser(IUser user);   // #3
}

interface IUserRepository
{
    IUser Create(string name);
    IUser GetByName(string name);
    void Remove(IUser user);
    void Save(IUser user);
}

interface IGroupRepository
{
    IGroup Create(string name);
    IGroup GetByName(string name);
    void Remove(IGroup group);
    void Save(IGroup group);
}
```

The tricky bit is to implement #1 #2 and #3 while keeping the entity classes (User, Group) decoupled from the repository classes (UserRepository, GroupRepository.)

Another technicality to consider is that most RMDB systems do not implement many-to-many relationships, and in practice there is always a separate table (say, UserGroupAssociation) to have records each associates a user and a group via foreign keys. I would like to hide this implementation detail from the domain interfaces and expose the equivalent logic through members #1 #2 and #3.

The effect of calling #2 and #3 should not persist until the group object in question has been saved (i.e. passed to the Save() method of the repository object)

How do you usually do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't do it. My `Repository` objects are tightly coupled to the root of the aggregate to which they relate, and (as kind of an aside) I don't bother making interfaces for my domain model objects unless I find I have a good reason to do so - do you have a particular reason to do this?

I've not come across any `Repository` examples which don't use the entity implementation type in the repository class ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601057/class-derived-from-generic-repository), for instance) and can't think of any real advantage of using an interface instead. Interfaces earn their keep for infrastructure components (like a `Repository`) by making it easier to mock out entire layers of the system when testing, you don't get the same type of advantage using interfaces for domain objects.

**And to perhaps actually answer the question...**

I never have a domain object access a `Repository` - the domain object after all is supposed to represent something in the domain in real life, and Repositories are infrastructure components that don't exist in real life, so why would a domain object know about one?

For the specific example of adding a `User` to a `Group`, I'd use a [Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) class, and do this:

```
public class UserService
{
    private readonly IGroupRepository _groupRepository;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserService(
        IGroupRepository groupRepository,
        IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this._groupRepository = groupRepository;
        this._userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void IncludeUserInGroup(string groupName, string userName)
    {
        var group = this._groupRepository.FindByName(groupName);
        var user = this._userRepository.FindByName(userName);

        group.IncludeUser(user);

        this._userRepository.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class User
{
    public void AddToGroup(Group group)
    {
        this.Groups.Add(group);
    }

    public void RemoveFromGroup(Group group)
    {
        this.Groups.Remove(group);
    }
}
```

Some points to note:

1. To avoid lazy-loading large numbers of `User`s when adding a `User` to a `Group` I've moved the `Group` administration methods onto `User` - depending on how much behaviour you actually have for `Group`, you might even consider turning it into an enumeration rather than a class. Be aware that if you're using the Entity Framework POCO T4 Templates with `FixupCollection`s, this will still lazy-load all the `User`s in a `Group`, but you can get around that in one way or another :)
2. The Service Layer class would implement a `Create()` method, the like of which you have on your Repositories. The Repositories would have an `Add` method, `Find` methods and a `SaveChanges()` method. `Add` would add an object created by the Service Layer to the object context.
3. All `Repository` classes would be set up to use the same underlying, request-scoped object context, so it wouldn't matter which one you call `SaveChanges()` on.
4. `SaveChanges()` would cause all changes which had happened to objects during that request to be saved, such as a `User` having a new `Group`'s added to their `Groups` collection.

Finally, another good technique for decoupling entities from Repositories and other infrastructure components is [Domain Events](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/).

Comment: The use of interface is to present a higher level of concept than just a bucket of properties to read/write. For example, instead of `class User{public byte[] PasswordHash{get;set;} }` wouldn't it be better if it is `interface IUser{bool VerifyPassword(string password);}` ?

Comment: In that example, couldn't you just make the `PasswordHash` property private (or protected, if you're limited by an ORM)? `User` will still have an implementation of `VerifyPassword()`, so it's not just going to be a bucket of properties.

Comment: For simple methods, that's quite true. But for others like IncludeUser() and ExcludeUser() (example #2 and #3) the implementation needs to access to the repository object, and not necessarily its own repository object. In the case of IncludeUser(), the Group class will need to talk to GroupRepository, UserGroupAssociationRepository. Having the entity to know the repository, however, is highly undesirable coupling.

Comment: Steve this is almost as good as I want it to be. The only grey area left is Group.Users collection in your example. If a group can include a large number of users it is certainly a good idea to only lazy load the collection when needed, yet it needs the capability to add and remove entities from the collection. How is that achieved?

Comment: I've updated my answer with reference to lazy loading. Happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks Steve! I am not using EF so I cooked up my own EntityCollection<T> class to lazy load and to record add/remove/clear operations which are replayed during repository.Save(). I hope this is the correct approach (it is working for me though.)

Comment: Sounds good, nice work! Happy to help, good luck with the project :)